# Cannot fetch the data after disabling cors

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Tried to load the data in with cors enabled it works fine, once I disable it I'm not able to get the data. Is there a work around without enabling cors?

This is the error I get: createHttpLink.js:96 Refused to connect to 'https://ms-gateway-f4b4o225iq-ue.a.run.app/graphql' because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.

Comment: this seems to be a CSP issue not a CORS issue

Answer (score 0):

Fetch No CORS

Bypass CORS for browser's Fetch API using https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere

```
Installation
```

npm:

> npm i fetch-no-cors

yarn:

> yarn add fetch-no-cors

```
Use
```

It's exactly like how we use the original fetch, you can either use it with await/async:

```
import fetchNoCors from "fetch-no-cors"

// You need to setup your own cors-anywhere proxy instance using https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere
const CORS_ANYWHERE = "https://my-own-cors-anywhere-proxy.com"
const foo = async (url, options, CORS_ANYWHERE) => {
  const res = await fetchNoCors(url, options)
  console.log(res)
}
```

or:

```
fetchNoCors(url, options, CORS_ANYWHERE)
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
```